# Multiple Parameters in React Router

Tags: reactjs

my application works fine with one parameter - id. How do I add more parameters in the routes, for example, campus, subject, etc. ?

```
 const Routing = () => ( 
    <HashRouter>
      <Route path='/course/:id' component={Parameters} /> 
      <Route path='/course/:CAMPUS_NAME' component={Campus} />
      <Route  path="/" component={App} />
    </HashRouter>
  </>
);

export default Routing;
```

Parameters.js

```
...
componentDidMount(){
              const {id} = this.props.match.params.id ;            
                this.runSearch();          
  }
...
```

Comment: What’s the problem with your implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with following way modifying the path attribute to

```
path="/course/:id/:campus/:subject"
```

In case of optional params try something like

```
path="/course/:id?/:campus?/:subject
```

To access the same you could use

```
this.props.match.params.param_value
Ex: this.props.match.params.campus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<Route path="/course/:id/:CAMPUS_NAME" component={MyPage} />
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I add  console.log debug code to  componentDidMount(){
          console.log("params",this.props.match.params); } to the MyPage component and reload page, there is no message on the console.